# Normalise data into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm trying to insert rows into a table (usersteps) from the table steps for all users only if the step id does not exist.

```
INSERT INTO userssteps
(status,user_id,step_id)
SELECT  
'0' , 
(SELECT DISTINCT id from users),
(SELECT DISTINCT id from steps)
```

I get the following error on the above MYSQL

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Reason:
A new user signs up they should get all steps, if I create a new step i'd want to create it in usersteps for current users to see.

If there is a more clever way to do this i'd love to know but i'm stumped. I am also using cakePHP so if there is a special cakePHP way to help me in this i'd prefer that.

Table Structure

```
steps:
id
name

users:
id
username
password

userssteps:
id
user_id
step_id
status
```

Comment: What is the use of the `user_id` column on the `steps` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to produce a cartesian product. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product.

If there is no relations between the users and steps table then they cannot be joined, only multiplied.

```
INSERT INTO userssteps
(status,user_id,step_id) 
select 0,
users.id,
steps.id
from users
inner join steps
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO userssteps
(status,user_id,step_id) 

select 0 as status,
users.id,steps.id
from users
inner join steps
on (users.id=steps.user_id);
```

That way should works ;)

PS: Now the join is right.

Saludos.

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like we are close except the below query returns zero results so nothing is inserted. At the moment three rows exists in steps and I have 2 users. So I would expect six rows to exist in the userssteps table. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have also included the table structure above.

Answer (score 0):

The subquerys (SELECT DISTINCT id from users) and (SELECT DISTINCT id from steps) will return ALL the id's. In a insert clause you will need only one value (you can't have more than 1 value).
you can try to inner join the two tables by the ID